# Kuzzle / how to dispatch event only to subscribed user based on a condition

Tags: kuzzle

I'm looking for the best approach to dispatch event to subscribed user based on user info condition.

My use case is:

- user with username = "A" subscribed to doc_created events (https://docs.kuzzle.io/sdk/js/7/controllers/realtime/subscribe/#subscribe)
- user with username = "B" also subscribed to doc_created events (same index + collection)
- Then I have a doc created with a field : forUser = "A"
- My goal is to dispatch the "doc_created" (https://docs.kuzzle.io/core/2/framework/events/generic-document/#generic-document-afterwrite) event only to user with username = "A" and drop the message that is sent to the user with username = "B".

Any advice for this use case?

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve that, the best way would be to inject users subscriptions with a filter on the documents `author` [metadata](https://docs.kuzzle.io/core/2/guides/main-concepts/data-storage/#kuzzle-metadata).

This injection could be done with a [pipe](https://docs.kuzzle.io/core/2/guides/develop-on-kuzzle/event-system/#pipe) on the `realtime:beforeSubscribe` event.

You need to modify the filters to include a clause on the document author but also keep the original filters with the and operator. You can get inspiration with this example:

```
app.pipe.register('realtime:beforeSubscribe', request => {
  request.input.body = {
    and: [
      {
        equals: { '_kuzzle_info.createdAt': request.context.user._id }
      },
      request.input.body
    ]
  };

  return request;
});
```